# Text parsing: Distinguish between "dictionary words" and names

Tags: java, parsing, text, dictionary

I have texts in English and German containing "dictionary words" and names.

> e.g. "... In Florence the painter Leonardo built ..."

I have a Java program where need to determine for each word if it is a name or a word of the respective language.

> e.g. names={..., Florence, Leonardo, ...}, language words={..., In, the, painter, built, ...}

I see two approaches:

1. use a respective dictionary list, load it into a hash structure, see if the word is in it (language word) or not (name / misspelled).

   Problems / Issues:

   I couldn't find a German word list where names are excluded

   word flexions (complicated in German) may not be in the list
2. use a service / an api to translate single words into another language, see if the word is changed (language word) or not (name / misspelled).

   Problems / Issues:

   names may be translated as well, e.g. Florence > Florenz

   I couldn't find an offline dictionary list / api. So I suppose using an online service is the way to go, but the big ones like google translate are not free.

Of course, there are names which resemble dictionary words and in both approaches they are identified as dictionary words which is fine.

**The main question is: Are there comprehensive dictionary lists without names in English and German, at best with word flexions?**

Alternatively:
Is there a free (online) API to do the task? Is there another solution?

Comment: I imagine it would be quite computationally expensive to test if a word is a name or not, by testing if its not in the dictionary or any other set. Perhaps there is a heuristic that you could apply to test if a word is PROBABLY a name...

Comment: I know a guy who's working on exactly this problem (German language parsing and grammar, where he has to identify names from words) as his AI doctorate..so I don't think there's any easy approach..

Comment: @SoulDZIN It does not matter if it completes fast. And besides, a lookup of a word in a hash, e.g. HashSet, even when filled with ten thousands of words, is really fast.

Comment: @shokkokkok Yes, but wouldn't there then be a memory cost if you were to do a hash lookup on a HashSet? This kind've problem sounds like you may want to build a 'isName' heuristic, rather than a lookup brute force method. Another consideration is, what if someone's name is the same as a dictionary word?.. (forgive me if I'm way off, I'm not familiar with German)

Comment: @SoulDZIN I don't think the memory would be an issue. Let's assume resources are no problem. But you are right, of course there are names that are dictionary words. In both approaches, they are identified as dictionary words, which is fine.

Comment: Your question is probably better suited for linguistics.stackexchange.com. I don't know the purpose of your classification, but you won't be able to find a 100% reliable solution, since there is a probably endless list of words, which are both "dictionary words" (as you call them) and names.

Answer (score 0):

You could find a lot of names by checking if the first letter is uppercase. After that you'll exclude all the ones that trail a end-of-sentence-character {".", "!", "?"}.

Assuming it's more of a story, it's pretty safe to assume a name will appear more than once. Use all the names you've already found and check them against a list of all the uppercase words that appeared after a end-of-sentence-character. Add those who are equal.

The 2nd part should only be done if you want every single occurrence, and not just the ones that occur.

At least, that's how I would approach it.

Edit: I'm not too familiar with the german language, but my approach will indeed have some issues with German. Refer to Joop Eggen's solution for that language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes German is a bit of a problem as non-name nouns are capitalized too.

There is one linguistic property though. Though one can say "the beautiful Florenz" ("das schöne Florenz"), for *personal* names the usage of article/adjective in front is very rare. The exception of plural, "the Müllers" ("die Müllers") could be considered too.

So you only need a list of geographical names and such.

And detect an article/adjective in front (der/die/das/... and -e/-en/-...).

Comment: I'm not looking for parsing phrases but single, isolated words. So in your example it would be acceptable if the algorithm identifies "the" as a language word and "Müllers" as a name, which is exactly what the usage of a dictionary hash without names would accomplish.

Comment: "Müller" (miller) on the other hand would be  identified as a dictionary word, which is fine.